# Using CMake to build a platform agnostic directory structure

Tags: python, c++, cmake, cross-platform, boost-python

I am trying to create a directory structure for my cross platform project and am running into some issue. I have CMake determine the appropriate place to put my libraries and executable, but the structure only holds up on Windows.

I have a structure that looks like the following:

- Project Directory

  - bin

    - executable
  - lib

    - libraries
  - python

    - boost modules
    - python scripts

This works fine on Windows, where I compile my module into a .pyd and place it in the python folder. The problem appears on my Linux build though. Instead of placing the boost-module.so into my python folder, it places it into my lib folder with the test library.

I have 3 CMakeLists.txt files currently. One is in my root project for my executable. The second is in a small test library I have written. The third is for a test boost::python module I have built that exports a class from the second. They are as follows, in the order listed above.

Base:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(renderer2d)

#enable debug symbols by default
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "")
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
endif()
#(you can also set on cl: -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release)

#place outside of Debug/Release folders
SET(OUTPUT_BINDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
MAKE_DIRECTORY(${OUTPUT_BINDIR})

SET(OUTPUT_LIBDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
MAKE_DIRECTORY(${OUTPUT_LIBDIR})

SET (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_LIBDIR} CACHE PATH "build     directory")
SET (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
IF(WIN32)
  SET (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH "build     directory")
ELSE(WIN32)
  SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_LIBDIR} CACHE PATH "build     directory")
ENDIF(WIN32)

# For each configuration (Debug, Release, MinSizeRel... and/or anything the     user chooses)
FOREACH(CONF ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
# Go uppercase (DEBUG, RELEASE...)
STRING(TOUPPER "${CONF}" CONF)
SET("CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_LIBDIR}")
SET("CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_BINDIR}")
IF(WIN32)
  SET("CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_BINDIR}")
ELSE()
  SET("CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_LIBDIR}")
ENDIF()
ENDFOREACH()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

#set the source directory
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)

add_subdirectory(shape)
add_subdirectory(py_shape)

#define sources and executable
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "renderer2d")
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES})

#find python
find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#detect and add SFML
#this line checks a cmake file for hints on where to find cmake
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
#find any version 2.x of SFML
#see the FindSFML.cmake file for additional details and instructions
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

#find and include Boost python libraries
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

#link all found libraries to the executable
if(WIN32)
    target_compile_definitions(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<BOOL:${MSVC}>:BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB>)
endif(WIN32)

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} shape)

#install target
install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
```

Test Library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#set the project name and type
project(shape CXX)

#test for windows
if(WIN32)
#build DLL
    include(GenerateExportHeader)
endif(WIN32)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

#set file variables
file(GLOB SOURCE src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB HEADERS inc/*.hpp)

#find packages
find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

#build the library
#test for Windows again
if(WIN32)
    #generate the export header for the .dll
    #generate_export_header(shape
    #                       BASE_NAME shape
    #                       EXPORT_MACRO_NAME shape_EXPORT
    #                       EXPORT_FILE_NAME shape_Export.h
    #                       STATIC_DEFINE shape_BUILT_AS_STATIC)
    add_library(shape STATIC ${SOURCE})
elseif(UNIX)
    add_library(shape SHARED ${SOURCE})
endif(WIN32)

#Enable C++11 if it is available
target_compile_features(shape PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
#link library
target_link_libraries(shape ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
#drop "lib" from the library name
set_target_properties(shape PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Boost Python module:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(py_shape CXX)

#set file variables
file(GLOB SOURCE src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB HEADERS inc/*.hpp)

#place outside of Debug/Release folders
SET(OUTPUT_BINDIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python)
MAKE_DIRECTORY(${OUTPUT_BINDIR})

SET(OUTPUT_LIBDIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
MAKE_DIRECTORY(${OUTPUT_LIBDIR})

SET (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_LIBDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
SET (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
IF(WIN32)
  SET (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
ELSE(WIN32)
  SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_LIBDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
ENDIF(WIN32)

# For each configuration (Debug, Release, MinSizeRel... and/or anything the user chooses)
FOREACH(CONF ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
# Go uppercase (DEBUG, RELEASE...)
STRING(TOUPPER "${CONF}" CONF)
SET("CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_LIBDIR}")
SET("CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_BINDIR}")
IF(WIN32)
  SET("CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_BINDIR}")
ELSE()
  SET("CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_LIBDIR}")
ENDIF()
ENDFOREACH()

#find packages
find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

#build the library
add_library(python_shape MODULE ${SOURCE})
#enable C++11 if available
target_compile_features(python_shape PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
#link library
target_link_libraries(python_shape shape ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
#drop "lib" from the library name
set_target_properties(python_shape PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

if(WIN32)
  #set extension to ".pyd"
  set_target_properties(python_shape PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".pyd")
endif(WIN32)
```

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

CMake documentation for [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) says:

> There are three kinds of target files that may be built: archive, library, and runtime. Executables are always treated as runtime targets. Static libraries are always treated as archive targets. Module libraries are always treated as library targets. For non-DLL platforms shared libraries are treated as library targets. For DLL platforms the DLL part of a shared library is treated as a runtime target and the corresponding import library is treated as an archive target. All Windows-based systems including Cygwin are DLL platforms.

So you need to change:

```
IF(WIN32)
  SET (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
ELSE(WIN32)
  SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_LIBDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
ENDIF(WIN32)
```

into:

```
SET (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
```

in your boost python CMakeLists.txt. Same for `${CONF}` variations.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. My boost module (.so) is still placed in my /lib directory on Linux. It doesn't change on Windows, still placed in the proper place. Any other ideas? At the very least, you helped streamline my CMakeLists.txt which is great.

Comment: I think nothing changed because you use `CACHE`. All paths are already set in "Base" CMakeLists.txt and cached and therefore do not get modified in "boost python" CMakeLists.txt. You can try to use `FORCE` in "boost python" CMakeLists.txt or don't cache / set paths globally etc. See CMake docs for [SET](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html).